# How to position checkbox label

Tags: jquery, html, css, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to position my checkbox label to a certain position using  *margin-top: 15px;* but for some reason, it's getting applied only to checkbox not the label but at the same time  *margin-right: 20px;* is getting applied to the label.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#lstStates').multiselect({});
});
```

```css
.multiselect-container label input {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.multiselect-container>li>a {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<select size="5" name="lstStates" multiple="multiple" id="lstStates">
  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="GG">asdfa</option>
  <option value="AW">jghjh</option>
  <option value="AE">qwer</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emozsaurab/ryo6b6g7/100/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's override by bootstrap css

just add this:

```
.multiselect-container>li>a>label.checkbox, 
.multiselect-container>li>a>label.radio {
    margin-top:15px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/can9key3/

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to position my checkbox label to a certain position using margin-top: 15px; but for some reason, it's getting applied only to checkbox not the label

Your selector only matches the `input`, it doesn't match the `label`.

> at the same time margin-right: 20px; is getting applied to the label.

No, it isn't.

Putting a margin on the right of the `input` moves whatever is to the right hand side of that away.

What is on the right-hand side is the text inside the label. So that text is moved.

The label itself doesn't get a right margin.

Since the input is inside the label, you need to apply your margin *to the label*, but since the stylesheet for the library you are using explicitly sets the label's margin, you need to use a more specific selector to override it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#lstStates').multiselect({});
});
```

```css
body .multiselect-container>li>a>label.checkbox,
body .multiselect-container>li>a>label.radio {
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.multiselect-container label input {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.multiselect-container>li>a {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<select size="5" name="lstStates" multiple="multiple" id="lstStates">
  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="GG">asdfa</option>
  <option value="AW">jghjh</option>
  <option value="AE">qwer</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for long explanation in a quick time, may I know how did you found exact selector  .multiselect-container>li>a>label.radio

Comment: @saurabhkumar — The element inspector in my browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Instead use `margin-top: 15px;` **only** to `.multiselect-container label input`

You have to use     `margin-bottom/top` **to all row** whats mean to `li`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#lstStates').multiselect({});
});
```

```css
.multiselect-container>li{
margin-top:15px;
}
.multiselect-container label input {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.multiselect-container>li>a {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<select size="5" name="lstStates" multiple="multiple" id="lstStates">
  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="GG">asdfa</option>
  <option value="AW">jghjh</option>
  <option value="AE">qwer</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `Margin` label

```
.multiselect-container label {
  margin-top:15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mkgjc8ub/

Comment: You forgot the existing CSS that the OP is using.

Comment: i am trying to position it bottom ,not middle

Comment: I think all CSS linking on jsfiddle